# Nvidia-Docker2 won't install in Cloudformation UserData bash script

Tags: bash, aws-cloudformation, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-docker

I have a cloudformation template that I have created in hopes to spin up an ec2 instance with the necessary dependencies (where these dependencies are installed as bash in UserData) to leverage GPU hardware within a docker container. The main dependencies are: 1) nvidia drivers, 2) docker, and 3) nvidia-docker2.

The first two dependencies install as expected and after several moments of running can be verified by 1) `nvidia-smi`, and `docker --version`. The third dependency however consistently *does not* install.

For reference here are the relevant parts of my UserData bash:

```
          # install gpu stuff
          apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
          distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID | sed -e 's/\.//g')
          wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distribution/x86_64/cuda-$distribution.pin
          mv cuda-$distribution.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
          apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distribution/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
          echo "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distribution/x86_64 /" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
          apt-get update
          apt-get -y install cuda-drivers

          # install docker on system
          curl https://get.docker.com | sh
          systemctl start docker && systemctl enable docker

          distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
          curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | apt-key add -
          curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

          apt-get -y install nvidia-docker2 > /var/log/mason

          # add nvidia runtime stuff
          # echo "{ \"runtimes\": { \"nvidia\": { \"path\": \"/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime\", \"runtimeArgs\": [] } } }" >> /etc/docker/daemon.json

          systemctl restart docker
```

I have tried to pipe the stdout from `apt-get -y install nvidia-docker2` to a log file but the logs only show:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
```

and seems to be stuck there.

Other potential helpful bits:

- AMI: ubuntu 18.04 image

I will also note that I am able to SSH into the instance and install the `apt-get -y install nvidia-docker2` in the command terminal without a hitch (or any user prompt or anything).

Can anyone help me figure out how to trouble shoot this issue or does anyone see any potential problems in what I have shared above? The stdout pipe to file is about the only trick I know to debug such an issue as this. Please let me know if I can update/edit this post to make this issue easier to debug.

Comment: Have you checked any logs for UserData to check what may be happening?

Comment: Hi, where would these logs be for UserData?

Comment: Ah I assume you mean the cloud-init-output.log file... Good call, I was previously looking in the term.log. So it looks like the cloud-init logs shows that "Unable to locate package nvidia-docker2" which is strange since I am adding the repository.

Comment: Do you run `apt-get update` after you add the repositry?

Comment: Indeed I did not, and this was my problem! Ha.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by not updating ubuntu's repositories after adding `nvidia-docker2` repo.

The **solution** was to run `apt-get update` after the addition of the repo.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID | sed -e 's/\.//g')
```

with:

```
distribution = ubuntu18.04
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).